# Regex - Splitting where there is a dot, but if quote mark appears after dot, split there

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, split, regex-lookarounds

I have to split this string (the quote marks are *included* in the string): `"This is a test. I need this to be splitted." And here is one with a question?`

**Wanted outcome**: `['"This is a test.', 'I need this to be splitted."', 'And here is one with a question?']`

**Description:**
The problem is that I need to split my text anywhere where there is either a `.!?;` but if there is a quotation mark appearing on the right of any of these signs, I need the split to occur *after* the quotation mark. I want to keep all punctuation marks or quote marks.

**Code:**
Right now I am doing this:

```
var str = '"This is a test. I need this to be splitted."';
let arr = str.match(/[^ ].+?(\.(?!;)|[?!:;])/g);
```

...but this doesn't fully work yet.

Comment: You could split on a space asserting what is on the right is a char A-Z. `(?=[A-Z])` or add a lookbehind for the dot on the left `(?<=\.) (?=[A-Z])` https://regex101.com/r/rNB6aK/1

Comment: To better understand the requirements, can you provide examples with question marks and desired output?

Comment: Added the question mark example - is this sufficient? Or shall I add more / other examples?

Comment: Do you mean like this? `(?<=[.!?;]) ?(?!(?:"|$))|(?<=") ` https://regex101.com/r/O30k2s/1

Comment: Please add an example with question mark which includes other punctuation marks as well to illustrate the actual problem with question marks

Comment: @NikosM. There is no problem with question marks, the problem is with quote marks. When there is a `.` I need there to be a split, most of the time. But when there is a `.` and after that there is `"` (so we get `."`), then I need to split after the quote mark. - or am I misunderstanding you?

Comment: @Thefourthbird what you posted looks correct! amazing!!

Comment: I see, i thought it was a typo and the problem was with question marks

Comment: Maybe `s.match(/[^?!.\s].*?[?!.]"?/g)` will do? See [the regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/UB3lS3/1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the example data, one option could be using an [alternation](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) `|` with lookarounds and then use [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split).

**Explanation**

- `(?<=[.!?;])` Positive lookbehind, assert what is directly to the left is one of `.!?;`
- Match a space (you could also use `\s+` for 1+ whitspace chars which might also match a newline)
- `(?!")` Negative lookahead, assert what is directly to the right is not `"`
- `|` Or
- `(?<=")`  Positive lookbehind, assert what is directly to the left is `"`. If that is true, match a space.

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ImxYyS/1)

```js
const regex = /(?<=[.!?;]) (?!")|(?<=") /g;
const str = `"This is a test. I need this to be splitted." And here is one with a question?`;
console.log(str.split(regex));
```

Answer (score 0):

`split` with

```
/(?<=[.!?;])\s+(?=[^\s"])|(?<=")\s+/
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/EJ5QvV/1). This splits strings with whitespaces that are either preceded with `.!?;` characters and followed with a character that is not whitespace and double quote, or with whitespaces that are preceded with `"`.

JavaScript:

```js
console.log(
  '"This is a test. I need this to be splitted." And here is one with a question?'.split(/(?<=[.!?;])\s+(?=[^\s"])|(?<=")\s+/)
)
```